# Test suite for SAT solvers

Tags: satisfiability

I'm looking for a collection of SAT problems that are usable for a test suite, *i.e.*:

1. are small/easy to solve, that is, this is not a benchmark but a correctness test suite
2. some satisfiable, some unsatisfiable
3. answer and a possible assignment (for sat. ones) is known

All I find online are collections of benchmarks but heavy formulas are not what I need.

Any link?

Comment: Generate such a collection yourself by generating random SAT formulas of the correct density, and using a known SAT solver do determine the correct answer (or even just exhaustive search). If you use the correct density, then you will get both positive and negative instances. Alternatively, you can choose a density in which most instances are negative and generate planted instances (in which some particular truth assignment is guaranteed to be satisfying).

Comment: Thanks! How do I generate instances of a given density?

Comment: *Density* is the ratio between the number of clauses and the number of variables, fixing the width of the clauses. I imagine that you know how to generate 3CNFs on $n$ variables with $m$ clauses.

Comment: Yes of course! I confused the density with something else XD

Comment: Anyway, I can generate the collection myself but I was asking for something available online. For example do existing SAT solvers have internal test suites?

Comment: I have no idea. If generating it yourself takes one hour, it might be faster than looking for something available online.

Comment: Yes, probably.. thanks!

Comment: In addition to Yuval's suggestion of randomly generating k-SAT formulae and taking density as a parameter, it might be worth pointing out that k-SAT densities exhibit a sharp *phase transition*. if your density is not close to the phase transition density, it is typically trivial to solve, almost all hard cases are at the the phase transition density.

Comment: There are plenty of collections of small SAT formulae online, e.g. [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html).